# A critical situation in which no trick works?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, single-word-requests, word-usage, vocabulary

How could one describe a situation in which no trick, no approach, no magic, nothing at all works to change the outcome? One where you have no choice but to accept things as they are.

For example, I can't use the excuse that I was ill for missed homework because I've already used it. Or when this happens with your boss?

What can I call such situation, in a single word, wherein you just have to accept  the blame, just have to give in to the situation you are in?

Comment: If you have no occasion for judgment or considered choice among options, the situation is not properly termed *critical.* In the archetypal dilemma, Odysseus had to accept that he would lose at least some of his men, but he still had a choice to make between Scylla and Charybdis, and used his (or perhaps rather Circe's) judgment to make that choice. In characterizing your hypothetical situation as *critical,* do you mean there is a real and important choice involved?

Comment: @BrianDonovan A situation of this sort is critical for OP's 'you' because it is a crisis, a turning-point; its outcome indeed rests on a choice (which may or not be 'considered' or rational), but the choice is not 'yours' but that of the person -the teacher, the boss- whom 'you' must confront.

Comment: Consider "at an *impasse*".

Comment: @jahanvi How is 25 answers *not enough attention*?

Comment: "There's no magic bullet" is a common idiom that nearly perfectly matches your title, but it fails to meet your "one word" criterium.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It's a...

> [***no-win*** situation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-win_situation)

...often summed up by saying you're...

> [*damned if you do, and [you're] damned if you don't*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=You%27re%20damned%20if%20you%20do%2C%20and%20you%27re%20damned%20if%20you%20don%27t.)

Sometimes it's appropriate to call it a...

> [***Catch-22*** [situation]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catch-22_(logic))

...where it's inherent in the context that you're required to simultaneously observe two or more mutually contradictory constraints. Particularly when successive solutions you come up with are ruled out because of additional constraints you didn't even know about until they were cited as reasons to reject those solutions.

---

If you are in such a situation, but you've [phlegmatically](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/phlegmatic) decided to accept it (and any associated *blame*) without indulging in further protestations against the "unreasonableness", you are...

> [***resigned***](http://oaadonline.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/resign) - because you *accept something unpleasant that cannot be changed or avoided*

Comment: There cannot be another word that expresses the meaning any more cogently. However, it is an adjective.  Isn't there a noun?

Comment: @vickyace: Obviously you could accept a no-win situation with an air of *resignation*, for example, for a **noun** usage. Or **adverbially** say that you have [resignedly accepted](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22resignedly+accepted%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) the situation. These and several other derived forms are all perfectly normal usages.

Comment: ha. That's what I thought.

Comment: @medica: It's certainly a no-win situation for me! After I answered, OP edited the question to make it clear he's asking about how to describe *being forced to admit you're at fault, purely because you've run out of excuses*. Arguably I can still be ***resigned*** to the fact that my answer is no longer *exactly* right, but unlike OP I don't feel "blameworthy". So whereas he can ***come clean, 'fess up,*** and ***face the music*** with his teacher, I can only ***take it on the chin***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers do you spend much time at tvtropes.org? ☺

Comment: @medica: I think these comments should stand for the time being, because they do at least shed some light on why my answer might have gained more upvotes than, for example, bib's (which currently seems far more targeted to the exact context of the question *text*). Perhaps there either are already existing questions more explicitly distinguishing the *"Forced to admit you've run out of excuses"* context from the *"Facing inherently insoluble dilemma"* one. Or they might get posted later. Either way, I'll happily closevote if and when anyone else flags a better-expressed duplicate (or two).

Comment: @MrBoJangles: <Guardedly> How much would you define as "much time" in such contexts? Personally, I try not to go there more than once every month or so, but that's because whenever I *do* visit tvtropes I tend to get lost there for several hours. But reading between the lines, yes - I agree with you it's a fascinating site.

Comment: +1 good answer, but I must disagree on the use of Catch-22 in this situation as I believe it has a fundamental difference from a "no-win" situation.

Comment: @Moo-Juice: As pointed out in my second comment above, the question text has changed since I answered. But even then I never said ***catch-22*** was appropriate to OP's exact context - simply that in closely-related contexts it might ***sometimes be appropriate***. But the question seems so loose (not to mention mercurial) that I'm starting to think it should be closed as "Unclear" anyway.

Comment: @FumbleFingers your bolding of key phrases reminded me of the website as you no doubt deduced. And it sounds like your experience there is the same as mine has been in terms of ***time no longer having meaning***.

Comment: I was going to write "resigned" but now I have no option but to up-vote the clarity of this answer :-).  @FumbleFingers, you should change your nickname to Nimble Fingers!

Comment: @Romulus: I wish! The truth is I type almost everything using just two fingers, so I'm incredibly slow *and* highly prone to typos.

Answer (score 24):

I think "[lost cause](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/lost+cause)" fits your description the best.

PS. I just reread the examples of your description and I think you should use "no way out" in those situations.

Answer (score 15):

Possibly obscure, but *[Kobayashi Maru](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kobayashi_Maru#Impact)*?  Although some might argue, in a *Kobayashi Maru* situation, a trick is exactly what is called for.

Comment: Depending on the audience, this could be *perfect*.

Comment: If this answer hadn't been here already, I was going to post it!

Comment: although I don't think that the kobayashi maru fits in this specific instance because of the fessing up portion, I would have given the same answer myself.

Answer (score 6):

Personally, I'd call the case in question a *blame game* (“A situation in which people attempt to blame others rather than trying to resolve a problem” – [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/blame_game)) or *blame fest* on the basis that it usually is someone else's fault when I'm blamed for a problem.

But more generally, when one cannot avoid something, one may refer to *an inexorable fate* (where *inexorable* means “Impossible to stop or prevent; inevitable” — [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/inexorable#Adjective)), or in that phrase replace *inexorable* with   *inevitable* (“Impossible to avoid or prevent” — [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/inevitable#Adjective)),  *predestined* (“foreordained by divine will” — [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/predestine#English)),  or *preordained* (“determined in advance; predestined” — [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/preordained)).

One might also refer to an *inevitability* (“An inevitable condition or outcome” — [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/inevitability)), a *foregone conclusion* (“A predictable or inevitable conclusion” — [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/foregone_conclusion)),  *the millstones of the gods* ([1](http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?t=168677),[2](http://www.special-dictionary.com/proverbs/keywords/mills/)), a *juggernaut* (“A literal or metaphorical force or object regarded as unstoppable, that will crush all in its path” — [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/juggernaut)), a *[mea culpa](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mea_culpa#Phrase)*, a *[peccavi](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/peccavi#Interjection)*, or something  *fated* (“Foreordained, predetermined, established in advance by fate” — [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fated)).

Comment: Inevitable is my obvious choice of word too for this one. I'm a bit surprised it is so low on the list of answers.

Comment: @Tonny, I was surprised that  *inevitable*, *inexorable*, and some others of these hadn't been mentioned, when I posted.  That was about half a day after the question was asked, and most views had already happened.

Answer (score 4):

There are numerous phrases that convey the acceptance of blame, such as

> - [come clean](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/come-clean)
> - [own up](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/own-up?q=own%20up)
> - ['fess up](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/fess?q=%27fess%20up#fess-2) (for *confess up*)
> - [take your lumps](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/lump?q=take%20your%20lumps#lump__21)
> - [take the blame](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/blame?q=take%20the%20blame#blame__12)
> - [make amends](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/amends?q=make%20amends)
>
> [all from ODO]

If you are just talking about the situation rather than the guilty persons response, you could say

> - [where the rubber meets the road](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/where+the+rubber+meets+the+road) [thefreedictionary.com]
> - [the shit hits the fan](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/when-the-shit-hits-the-fan?q=shit%20hits%20the%20fan) (considered vulgar) [ODO]
> - [up the creek without a paddle](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/be-up-the-creek-without-a-paddle?q=up%20the%20creek) [ODO]
> - [up shit creek](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=up%20shit%20creek) (also vulgar) [the Urban Dictionary]
> - [in the crosshairs](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+the+cross+hairs) [thefreedictionary.com]
> - [the end of the line](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/end?q=end%20of%20the%20line#end__50) [ODO]
> - no way out

Answer (score 4):

How about *fate*, *destiny*, *pre-ordained*, or another word along those lines?  They all embody the concept of a future that is already written.

Answer (score 4):

Such a situation is sometimes referred to as a *cul-de-sac* or a *dead end*.

Answer (score 3):

### Impossible to avoid or prevent

**inevitable** *adjective*
impossible to avoid or prevent

**unavoidable** *adjective*
impossible to stop from happening

**inescapable** *adjective*
impossible to avoid or ignore

**unstoppable** *adjective*
impossible to prevent or stop

**uncontrollable** *adjective*
if a situation or event is uncontrollable, you cannot stop it, change it, or improve it

**irresistible** *adjective*
impossible to refuse, not want, or not like

**compulsive** *adjective*
impossible to control and therefore sometimes harmful

**inexorable** *adjective*
impossible to stop

**irrevocable** *adjective*
impossible to change or stop

**cannot/can’t help something**
used for saying that someone cannot stop themselves doing something

[Source: MacMillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/thesaurus-category/british/Impossible-to-avoid-or-prevent)

Answer (score 2):

sounds like you *painted yourself into a corner*

http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/paint+into+a+corner

Answer (score 1):

The words "hopeless", "fruitless", or "futile" come to mind for me. Given the definitions below, futile seems to best fit your needs.

def:

- hopeless: feeling or causing despair about something.
- fruitless: failing to achieve the desired results; unproductive or useless.
- futile: incapable of producing any useful result; pointless

eg:

- Given my instructor's strict policy on late assignments, my chances at convincing him otherwise leaves me hopeless.
- A two our argument with my instructor over my late assignment proved fruitless.
- To argue with my stubborn instructor over a late assignment would simply be futile.

Cheers.

Comment: Welcome! I realize this is a fairly straightforward answer; still, linking to a definition, or putting one in as a reference, might help people see exactly **why** these words come to your mind as synonyms. Edit your answer [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/185216/edit) and you'll be ready for your first upvote!

Answer (score 1):

The best word I can think of is that it would be *inevitable*. It means certain to happen, or unavoidable, which fits the bill.

Answer (score 1):

**FUBAR** is a neologism created from the informal military acronym for *f@#$ed up beyond all repair*, referring to a situation where there is no solution that will provide positive results.

There are bowlderized versions for sensitive ears, such as *fouled up beyond all repair/recognition*.

And there is the **TARFU** variant, meaning *totally and royally f@#$ed up*.

Related is *SNAFU* for *situation normal, all f@#$ed up*.

And in the same vein, if you are the unfortunate person in such a situation, the you are simply *f@#$ed*.

Comment: In FUBAR, the R stands for "Recognition" | I'm sure that there are other versions, but "Beyond All Recognition" is the classic version that I have always heard. "Repair" sort of implies that we are talking about a mechanical failure.  "FUBAR" was used to describe orders by incompetent officers. In military parlance, "the situation is FUBAR" means something to the effect of "we're probably going to die because we're being led by a moron."

Answer (score 1):

What you would want is to *mitigate* the consequences of your behaviour, meaning *make (something bad) less severe, serious, or painful* (Oxford dictionary). But, to make it one word, the situation is *unmitigable* (found in a few dictionaries, [usage examples](https://www.learnthat.org/dictionary/90604_unmitigable.html)).

Answer (score 1):

Such circumstances are often referred to as a [*fait accompli*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fait-accompli), borrowing from the French.

A situation which cannot be changed and has been imposed by others.

Answer (score 1):

'Hobson's Choice'--means one is given a choice but permitted only one choice. Named after Thomas Hobson (1544-1631) a livery stable owner in Cambridge England. To rotate his horses Hobson gave his customers the choice of taking the stall nearest the stable door or taking no stall at all. Hobson's choice is no choice.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to suggest ***inextricable*** as an adjective. It is used with situation or fate also which fits well to the idea. It is also used in technical contexts.

> Unavoidable; inescapable: *bound together by an inextricable fate.*
>
> <sub>Source: http://www.thefreedictionary.com</sub>

As a noun, I can suggest ***impasse***. It is often used in bargaining and discussions but you can apply to other situations as well.

> A situation that is so difficult that no progress can be made; a deadlock or a stalemate: *reached an impasse in the negotiations.*
>
> <sub>Source: http://www.thefreedictionary.com</sub>

As an idiomatic phrase, there is ***behind the eight-ball***. It is used in very difficult situations with no solution or escape.

> *(idiomatic)* In a difficult situation or tight spot.
>
> *After his last two projects failed, he was really behind the eight-ball. 
>
>   He was desperate, playing behind the eight-ball.*
>
> <sub>Source: http://en.wiktionary.org</sub>

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly about the situation itself, but about the action.

**There's nothing left but to bite the bullet.**

*Biting the bullet* is an idiom for accepting the simple, obvious negative consequences. It's the opposite to *worming your way out*. You got in trouble, you plead guilty and accept the punishment.

Answer (score 0):

What about

> at mercy

All of these answers are suggesting that the author is trying to describe a negative outcome. To me he seems to be trying to describe a situation where he is 'at the mercy of' an authority/situation/weather, having extinguished all of his possible action points.

"At mercy" is not inherently desperate, it just shows acceptance and submission to the end-result, not necessarily hopeless but without any option other than waiting for an outcome, external to yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Responding to the updated question where you've clarified that you're hopelessly trapped and cannot escape, I suggest the most idiomatic description is:

> They've got you ***cornered***

Which is self-explanatory.

Please note the distinction from @Joseph Neathawk's

> Painted yourself into a corner

In the former scenario, *they* cornerned you; in the latter *you* cornered *yourself*.

Answer (score 0):

- *no exit*
- *boxed in*
- *hemmed in*
- *at an impasse*
- *in a blind alley*
- *at a dead end*
- *reached a stalemate* (not quite the same)
- *deadlocked* (not quite the same)
- *dead wrong*
- *guilty*

Answer (score 0):

I have always considered such a situation where an act "must" be performed although an undesirable outcome is deemed inevitable a

> **Death March.**

In business, there is a management antitype known as "Management by Death March" in which a project's prospects for satisfactory completion borders on nil but Management insists that rather than call the project a failure, cease from throwing good money after bad, and living to fight another day, they order a Death March.  In a Death March, workers are pushed to commit excessive effort for little to no gain or have additional compensation incentivized by goals that management know are unreasonable or -in a more insidious case- have already been proven to have failed.

Another, more formal term for such a situation in which an act must be performed with a bad outcome already foreseen is a

> **Sisyphean Task**

In the story of Sisyphus, Hades condemned him to a fate in which he must roll a rock up a steep hill only to have it roll back down on him near the top, in perpetuity.

If you are speaking more broadly of any situation in which an outcome is unstoppable, that outcome is known as

> **inexorable**

Answer (score -1):

The situation of having no **recourse**.

Answer (score -2):

It’s not just one single word, but from the context it sounds like it’s “time to face the music.”

Answer (score -2):

Dire straights man.

Or an "impossible situation" - a situation where no resolution or victory is possible.

Comment: That's spelled *[dire straits](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dire_straits)*, not *straights*.  Also, Wiktionary says “A difficult position” rather than an impossible one.

Answer (score -3):

Resigned or taken-aback.

I am going to prefer either of both.

Comment: -1 *resigned* was in an answer posted weeks ago, and *taken-aback* (which doesn't have a hyphen) is completely inappropriate for the context. I don't understand how the bounty comes to be awarded to this answer, which has nothing to commend it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's the way the site works. Anyone can accept whatever answer they please, anyone can give a bounty to whatever answer they please. You could just stick a 500 instant reward on this answer if you wanted. But you already know that so "What do points make?" ...

Comment: @Frank: I don't know if whoever posted the bounty explicitly *selected* this answer, or if the system auto-allocated it. If the former, I suppose the guy must have had a reason - but to be honest I never understood why anyone would put a bounty on this question in the first place. If the latter, I'd like to know more about the auto-allocation algorithm.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Maybe the whole point was for one guy to transfer 200 reps to his friend. That makes a lot more sense than attributing it to actual quality of answer, since this is in fact a duplicate answer and should probably be deleted because of that.

Comment: @FumbleFingers If you look at the edit history you'll see it was a manually applied bounty (but it was near the end of the bounty period). There was another bounty on this question earlier (50+ I think) but it passed the bounty expiry date automatically as the bounty 'offerer' was suspended at the time of expiration.