# What is anti-money and how do I launder it?

Tags: hyphenation

So the phrase "anti-money laundering" has an obvious meaning, referring to something or some process that acts against the laundering of money.  However, I find the use of the hyphen slightly confusing.  Lets try another example:

"anti-gravity modulation"

Is this something that acts against the modulation of gravity, or is it the modulation of anti-gravity (as in: my anti-gravity boots keep me stable because they use anti-gravity modulation).

Does this just come down to context or am I using incorrect grammar (or am I just confused)?

Comment: It's usually hyphenated **anti-money laundering** because [*money laundering*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Money_laundering) is an established non-hyphenated two-word term, so it would be odd to suddenly introduce a hyphen there. By the same token, there's no such thing as **lock brakes** (hyphenated or not), so we don't slip a hyphen in there just because we want to refer to **anti-lock brakes**.

Comment: Note that in speech, you would use stress to disambiguate this situation.

Comment: I think it would be more correctly written 'anti-money-laundering' as in 'The current anti-money-laundering regulations require rigorous proof of identity when bank accounts are opened'.

Comment: @FumbleFingers But if 'money laundering' is used as a pre-positioned adjective you would have to employ a hyphen, wouldn't you? And how would you use 'anti-money-laundering' other than as a pre-positioned adjective?

Comment: In a quick check on the internet, I've found the three variants (for the attributive usage)  anti money laundering,  anti-money laundering and  anti-money-laundering. One could argue that 'money laundering' is such a well-known collocation that it doesn't need a hyphen, while 'anti', being a bound lexeme, does. So the variant you cite gets my vote. However, anti-gravity is a compound, so the hyphen isn't readily omissible. If one chooses the allowed solid form, the ambiguity is resolved: antigravity modulation.

Comment: ... If the alternative were needed (I'm not sure it makes sense), anti-(gravity modulation) would work, though some will cry out that you have to have 17 different types of dashes and hyphens to hand for cases like this.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You have only one dash for this: the EN DASH, which can be used instead of a hyphen to separate a prefix from an open or hyphenated compound.  For *(anti-abortion) legislation* I think anyone would prefer *antiabortion legislation*, although for someone who is *anti-(abortion legislation)*, the *anti–abortion legislation* or *anti–abortion-legislation* forms which are sometimes recommended are, as I have said before, not especially satisfying. My general recommendation is to use only has much decoration as is needed to disambiguate. Modern trends seem to use too many hyphens.

Comment: @WS2: Nobody ***has*** to put a hyphen in two-word pre-positioned adjective usages - we usually do it to improve legibility, is all. Apparently writers in general are [about 50-50 split on this particular one](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=money+laundering+scheme%2Cmoney-laundering+scheme&year_start=1980&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmoney%20laundering%20scheme%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmoney%20-%20laundering%20scheme%3B%2Cc0). I think thsat's because half of them think like you that there's a "rule" in play here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers as an engineer I have seen brakes that lock after being turned on (similar to the hand-break in a car).  Are you saying I can't call them Lock Brakes?

Comment: @Ben: I suppose you could. But I'd think more likely they'd be called ***locking brakes*** if you wanted to market them.

Comment: @FumbleFingers yes that would be a better name.  So as a non-language specialist, or should that be non language-specialist ;-) this all comes down to context and a working knowledge of which words usually fit together, is that right?

Comment: @Ben: That's a bit of a [*damned if you do, damned if you don't*](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/185062/2637) example for me. Interestingly, of the [four instances in Google Books for **"a non language specialist"**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a+non+language+specialist%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) two only include the first hyphen, and the other two go for broke.

Comment: Pertinent xkcd: http://xkcd.com/37/

Comment: @tchrist (Real writing not having been banned yet) I'm afraid that my en dash can be confused with my tilde.